# What is a runtime as a data structure?

Tags: frame, runtime

After a runtime is complete and all the macros are expanded, what kind of data structure is the runtime?

e.g.
Is the Runtime a struct? If so, what are some of the fields? I want to be able to build a mental model of what exactly I am building; when trying to "see definition" for the runtime I am told it is a struct in some cases and enum in others, i suspect this has to do with the macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Runtime is a struct which implements a bunch of traits, for example all the `Config` traits required by the pallets you include in your runtime.

You can look at the Runtime generated by the `substrate-node-template` here:

https://crates.parity.io/node_template_runtime/struct.Runtime.html

> If so, what are some of the fields?

The `Runtime` struct has no fields. It just holds of all the trait implementations, and exposes the `metadata()` function.